# python sorting lines in a file beginning with numbers in the right order

Tags: python, python-3.x, line

I have a file which looks like:

```
11 -7.072985E-17  5.570644E-18  2.763979E-17
12 -6.420375E-17 -5.456010E-19  2.229937E-17
9 -8.360102E-17  1.172390E-17  2.492073E-17
10 -1.046834E-16  1.106907E-17  1.840354E-17
17  2.000000E-01  1.172390E-17  2.492073E-17
18  2.000000E-01  1.106907E-17  1.840354E-17
19  2.000000E-01  5.570644E-18  2.763979E-17
20  2.000000E-01 -5.456010E-19  2.229937E-17
2  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
6  2.000000E-01  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
4  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
1  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
13 -8.360102E-17  1.172390E-17  2.492073E-17
14 -1.046834E-16  1.106907E-17  1.840354E-17
15 -7.072985E-17  5.570644E-18  2.763979E-17
16 -6.420375E-17 -5.456010E-19  2.229937E-17
3 -0.000000E+00 -0.000000E+00 -0.000000E+00
5  2.000000E-01 -0.000000E+00 -0.000000E+00
7  2.000000E-01 -0.000000E+00 -0.000000E+00
8  2.000000E-01 -0.000000E+00 -0.000000E+00
21  2.000000E-01  1.172390E-17  2.492073E-17
22  2.000000E-01  1.106907E-17  1.840354E-17
```

how can i order the lines so that it will change the order of it resulting in lines starting  with 1,2,.... looking like:

```
1  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
2  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
.....
21  2.000000E-01  1.172390E-17  2.492073E-17
```

Comment: what is the file format? comma separated file (.csv) ?

Comment: its a textfile.. right now iam trying it with pandas sort.value()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I asked for the file type is that the code depends a bit on how you read it. But if I just take your data as given above and input as a list of lists, then the below code will sort as you ask.

```py
import pandas as pd
dat = [['11', '-7.072985E-17', '5.570644E-18', '2.763979E-17'],
       ['12', '-6.420375E-17', '-5.456010E-19', '2.229937E-17'],
       ['9', '-8.360102E-17', '1.172390E-17', '2.492073E-17'],
       ['10', '-1.046834E-16', '1.106907E-17', '1.840354E-17'],
       ['17', '2.000000E-01', '1.172390E-17', '2.492073E-17'],
       ['18', '2.000000E-01', '1.106907E-17', '1.840354E-17'],
       ['19', '2.000000E-01', '5.570644E-18', '2.763979E-17'],
       ['20', '2.000000E-01', '-5.456010E-19', '2.229937E-17'],
       ['2', '0.000000E+00', '0.000000E+00', '0.000000E+00'],
       ['6', '2.000000E-01', '0.000000E+00', '0.000000E+00'],
       ['4', '0.000000E+00', '0.000000E+00', '0.000000E+00'],
       ['1', '0.000000E+00', '0.000000E+00', '0.000000E+00'],
       ['13', '-8.360102E-17', '1.172390E-17', '2.492073E-17'],
       ['14', '-1.046834E-16', '1.106907E-17', '1.840354E-17'],
       ['15', '-7.072985E-17', '5.570644E-18', '2.763979E-17'],
       ['16', '-6.420375E-17', '-5.456010E-19', '2.229937E-17'],
       ['3', '-0.000000E+00', '-0.000000E+00', '-0.000000E+00'],
       ['5', '2.000000E-01', '-0.000000E+00', '-0.000000E+00'],
       ['7', '2.000000E-01', '-0.000000E+00', '-0.000000E+00'],
       ['8', '2.000000E-01', '-0.000000E+00', '-0.000000E+00'],
       ['21', '2.000000E-01', '1.172390E-17', '2.492073E-17'],
       ['22', '2.000000E-01', '1.106907E-17', '1.840354E-17']]

df = pd.DataFrame(dat)
df[0] = df[0].astype(int)
df = df.sort_values(by=0)
print(df)
```

Comment: thank you man my mistake before was that i had to specify df = pd.read_table('/file.dat', delim_whitespace=True, header=None) because of the seperator. your code worked afterwards. thanks appreciate

Answer (score 0):

this is how i import the data file into panda:

dat = pd.read_table('file.dat')

this is what i get when i print dat on console:

```
    11 -3.948718E+01  1.949635E-15  1.410256E+01
0   12 -3.948718E+01 -6.501868E-17  1.410256E+01
1    9 -3.948718E+01 -1.410256E+01  3.356932E-15
2   10 -3.948718E+01 -1.410256E+01 -2.664535E-15
3   17  3.948718E+01 -1.410256E+01 -8.127297E-16
4   18  3.948718E+01 -1.410256E+01  0.000000E+00
5   19  3.948718E+01  1.827238E-16  1.410256E+01
6   20  3.948718E+01  1.155508E-15  1.410256E+01
7    2 -1.974359E+01 -7.051281E+00 -7.051281E+00
8    6  1.974359E+01 -7.051281E+00 -7.051281E+00
9    4 -1.974359E+01  7.051281E+00 -7.051281E+00
10   1 -1.974359E+01 -7.051281E+00  7.051281E+00
11  13 -3.948718E+01  1.410256E+01  4.476929E-15
12  14 -3.948718E+01  1.410256E+01 -2.664535E-15
13  15 -3.948718E+01 -8.148796E-18 -1.410256E+01
14  16 -3.948718E+01 -3.394488E-15 -1.410256E+01
15   3 -1.974359E+01  7.051281E+00  7.051281E+00
16   5  1.974359E+01 -7.051281E+00  7.051281E+00
17   7  1.974359E+01  7.051281E+00  7.051281E+00
18   8  1.974359E+01  7.051281E+00 -7.051281E+00
19  21  3.948718E+01  1.410256E+01 -1.777104E-15
20  22  3.948718E+01  1.410256E+01  1.776357E-15
21  23  3.948718E+01  7.707988E-16 -1.410256E+01
22  24  3.948718E+01  1.244052E-15 -1.410256E+01
23  25 -2.770623E-15 -1.410256E+01 -1.410256E+01
24  26 -4.023945E-15 -1.410256E+01 -1.410256E+01
25  27 -1.857338E-15 -1.410256E+01  1.410256E+01
26  28 -1.539070E-16 -1.410256E+01  1.410256E+01
27  29  9.707337E-16  1.410256E+01 -1.410256E+01
28  30  1.464331E-15  1.410256E+01 -1.410256E+01
29  31  1.440271E-14  1.410256E+01  1.410256E+01
30  32 -4.891681E-17  1.410256E+01  1.410256E+01
31  33 -7.897437E+01 -2.161541E-15  1.056976E-15
32  34 -7.897437E+01  1.371012E-15  2.697062E-15
33  35 -7.897437E+01 -7.295245E-16  1.776357E-15
34  36 -7.897437E+01  6.085350E-16  0.000000E+00
35  37  7.897437E+01  9.540498E-16 -7.105427E-15
36  38  7.897437E+01 -2.194593E-15 -1.776357E-15
37  39  7.897437E+01  4.515291E-15 -2.437956E-15
38  40  7.897437E+01  4.610022E-16 -5.525260E-15
39  41 -1.897793E-14 -2.820513E+01 -8.599718E-16
40  42 -1.879454E-15 -2.820513E+01  0.000000E+00
41  43  1.624346E-14 -2.820513E+01  7.492733E-15
42  44  1.469293E-15 -2.820513E+01  1.776357E-15
43  45  2.232466E-14  2.820513E+01 -2.357996E-15
44  46 -2.967245E-15  2.820513E+01  3.552714E-15
45  47 -1.648585E-15  2.820513E+01  8.332369E-15
46  48 -2.305978E-15  2.820513E+01 -1.776357E-15
47  49 -2.311771E-15 -3.830187E-16 -2.820513E+01
48  50 -5.195924E-15 -7.095857E-15 -2.820513E+01
49  51  2.040643E-14 -6.509591E-15 -2.820513E+01
50  52 -2.319451E-14 -1.946982E-15 -2.820513E+01
51  53  9.340751E-15  2.214389E-16  2.820513E+01
52  54 -1.162885E-14 -9.364264E-16  2.820513E+01
53  55  1.161707E-14  6.326350E-15  2.820513E+01
54  56  1.477891E-14  4.364906E-16  2.820513E+01
```